# In java If a thread calls notify() before wait(), how does this not cause the second thread to enter the block before the first goes to wait state?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I Wrote the following code to run one thread to print even numbers and the other to print odd numbers using the same counter variable. However, I am wondering what internal mechanism causes notify() to trigger only after wait(), even if notify() is called before wait() and there is an operation in between.

As in T1 issues notify() but goes in wait() state only after iterating 10000 times. Shouldn't t2 already try and get the lock as soon as notify is triggered or does notify() by design wait for wait() to be invoked?

PS: I see that irrespective of where I put the notify() call, it is always invoked after wait() as long as I write it before the wait() call.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class PrintThread implements Runnable {

int i = 0;
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void run() {

    synchronized (lock) {
        while (i <= 10) {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " i is " + i);
            i++;
            lock.notify();

            //Just to add some delay
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){}

            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Exiting!");
    }
}}
```

And the Driver Program

```
public class PrintThreadDriver {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    PrintThread obj1 = new PrintThread();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(obj1);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}}
```

Output:

`Thread-0 i is 0
Thread-1 i is 1
Thread-0 i is 2
Thread-1 i is 3
Thread-0 i is 4
Thread-1 i is 5
Thread-0 i is 6
Thread-1 i is 7
Thread-0 i is 8
Thread-1 i is 9
Thread-0 i is 10
Thread-1 Exiting!`

Also I see that one of the thread continues to be in wait state. Any Ideas as to how I can cause that to terminate once the counter reaches 10?

Comment: What error? It notifies one of the threads hat are waiting. There can be zero or more of those. It doesn't care.

Comment: @EJP There is no error, just wanted to know how notify doesn't invoke the other waiting thread immediately. Edited to add more details.

Comment: I am referring to the error mentioned in your title. What is the meaning of that, if it isn't part of your question?

Comment: @EJP Corrected the Title?

Comment: So when I ask 'what error' and you answer 'there is no error' what you really mean is 'concurrent access error'? Why not say so in the first place? My question now is 'what is this concurrent access error' mentioned in your title? I'm not aware of such a thing in Java. What is the basis for your expectation that it should occur?

Answer (score 3):

For lock object you have **wait set** and **blocked set**.

Here what is happening in your program:

1. The First thread is started, the monitor is locked (lock is captured)
2. The Second thread is started, but since the monitor is locked the second thread goes to Blocked Set.
3. The first thread prints "Thread-0 i is 0", do operations and calls notify from lock. Nothing is happening because notify removes a random thread from wait set. For now we have an empty wait set. The second thread is still in blocked set.
4. The first thread waits a little in a spin-lock, calls wait and goes to wait set. The monitor is unlocked, the Second thread takes the monitor and starts working, The monitor is taken by the second thread.
5. The second thread prints "Thread-1 i is 1" and calls notify. The first thread is removed from wait set and goes to blocked set since the monitor is still tacked by the second thread. The second thread calls wait and goes to wait set. The monitor is unlocked.
6. The first thread takes the monitor and continue working from the line when it called lock.wait().
7. The first thread continue the loop and prints "Thread-0 i is 2" and then calls notify. The second thread is removed from wait set and placed to blocked set. The first thread calls wait and goes to wait set. The monitor is unlocked.
8. The second thread takes the monitor and continue working from the line when it called lock.wait().
9. The second thread continue the loop and prints "Thread-1 i is 3" and then calls notify. The first thread is removed from wait set and placed to blocked set. The second thread calls wait and goes to wait set. The monitor is unlocked.
10. Items 6-9 are repeated while i < 10.

Now, lets describe the last iteration:

11. i=10. The second thread is in wait set. The monitor is blocked by the first thread. The first thread continue the loop and prints "Thread-0 i is 10". Then the first thread calls notify, the second thread is removed from wait set and goes to blocked set. The first Thread calls wait and goes to wait set. The monitor is unlocked.
12. The second thread takes the monitor and continue working from the line when it called lock.wait().
13. The second thread exits the loop because i==11, prints "Thread-1 Exiting!" and unlocks the monitor. The Second thread is finished.
14. The monitor is unlocked, but the first thread is still in wait set and it will be there forever because nobody will call notify! (Except spurious wakeup case)

Since the thread first thread is not demon the program will not finished.
For you case just duplicate `lock.notify();`  right after the loop to remove the first thread from wait set and to let him to finish.

All needed proofs and confirmations of the behavior described below you can find here:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

PS: Notify will never invoke the other waiting thread immediately. It will just remove a thread from **Wait Set** and then this thread will be invoked by the **Operating System**! And if the thread will try to enter to the locked monitor (synchronized block) that is already taken by another thread, it will be placed to the blocked set until it can obtain the lock on that monitor.

Comment: There's nothing in your citation about 'blocked sets'.

Comment: @EJP 17.1 Synchronization. "...Only one thread at a time may hold a lock on a monitor. !!!Any other threads attempting to lock that monitor ARE BLOCKED until they can obtain a lock on that monitor."
So, blocked set it's just an abstract concept that means one ore more threads are blocked at the entrance to the monitor. I use term "Blocked Set" for more  understandable, because if there are more than one thread blocked, only one random thread(chosen by OS) will obtain the monitor after it's unlocked. Blocked Set of threads means some amount of blocked treads without order for the monitor.

Answer (score 2):

> In java If a thread calls notify() before wait(), how does this not cause the second thread to enter the block before the first goes to wait state?

Because the first thread still holds the lock until it calls `wait()` or exits the `synchronized` block. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()):

> The awakened thread wil be unable to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

Comment: My understanding is that to notify means to give a go for entering the Critical section, but lets say there are some operations between the Notify and wait(), why is it that the other thread waits for the current thread to exit the critical section, does this also mean that as soon as notify is called, one of the thread will exit the sleep state and constantly check on the lock to see when its available, will it consume CPU cycles then?

Comment: @Sameer Your question doesn't make sense. The other thread is in `wait()`. That's why it is waiting. If it isn't in `wait()` when `notify()` is called, it won't get notified. `wait()` is almost certainly not implemented with spin-locks.

Answer (score 0):

Wait means that the current thread which has the lock, will give out the lock to another thread in the thread pool, the next thread that acquire the lock(decided by thread scheduler) will complete the task and then notify back to the previous thread with notify().  After notify() then the waiting thread which gave the lock will resume its task.

Comment: Q1: Let's say Thread 0 enters first, what happens to Thread 1 in the meantime, does it automatically go into wait state?
Q2: If thread 0 is the first thread to enter, notify() is still called before the wait() is triggered going by sequential flow, what happens to this notify() call?

Comment: Q1:If Thread 0 enters first then Thread 1 is on the Thread Pool.  If Thread 0 calls static wait() method then Thread 0 gives the lock to the next thread(next thread can only be determined by the thread scheduler, unless you give it priority) .  Q2: notify() will be called when Thread 2 has obtained the lock.  Considering you are aware of how inter-thread communication happens then only a single thread will be able to obtain the lock for that defined synchronized method/block.

Comment: What happens when on the first entry into the synchronized block, the first thread encounters the notify(), is it ignored?

Comment: The other thread cannot notify the current thread in the synchronized block/method because in a synchronized block/method only the current thread is allowed to execute, hence we use wait, to give the lock to other threads in the thread pool.

Comment: There is no 'thread pool' here, and the thread that receives the `notify()` does not 'notify back to the previous thread with `notify()`'.

Comment: Still didn't answer my question, I understand the mechanism, but if we go sequentially, notfiy() comes before wait(), I did some experimentation, I see irrespective of where I place the notify(), it is always after the wait that notify is invoked

Comment: @newBy The `wait()` method is not static, and priority is not involved. You're just adding to the confusion.